# A multiplication for complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

I just found a formula on our lecture notes which is as follow:

$(a + bi)(c + di) = (ac − bd) + (ad + bc)i$.

but when I compute this, my result is:

$(a + bi)(c + di) = ac + adi + bci + bdi$

where $i = (0, 1)$

And it says that by the formula we have $i^2 = -1$

Anyone can give me a short explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dropped one of the $i$'s when you multiplied $bi$ with $di$.

$$\begin{align} (a+bi)(c+di) &= a(c+di)+bi(c+di) \\
&=ac+adi+bci+bdi^2 \\
&=ac+adi+bci+bd*(-1) \\
&=ac+adi+bci-bd \\
&=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i
\end{align}$$

Comment: God.....I'm silly. Thank you